# What does "cyclic data flow" mean in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark is a DAG execution engine. Are not cyclic and DAG opposite concepts? It's surprising hard to find the answer to this apparent contradiction.

As you can see here: [Understanding your Apache Spark Application Through Visualization](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html), it is possible to visualize the execution DAG using the Spark UI. However, none of the examples in that page shows a cyclic data flow. In the following image you can see one of these examples.

[Spark execution DAG example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpxzr.png)

Can these iterations (cyclic data flows) be outside the graph? I have read in *MAPR* that "Each Spark job creates a DAG of task stages to be performed on the cluster". Then, maybe the cyclic data flow occurs between DAGs (jobs).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems that it was a typo or something in the documentation. As of today, we can find this in the [Spark homepage](http://spark.apache.org/):

> Apache Spark has an advanced DAG execution engine that supports **acyclic** data flow and in-memory computing.